# Как к числу в переменной добавить +1 каждые 48 часов php

Tags: php, wordpress, дата

Вопрос 1.

Есть сайт, на котором можно забронировать билеты на автобус. Есть автобус маршрутом "Начало - Конец", и отправляется он, к примеру сегодня. На сегодняшний день номер его рейса - 000001. 
Послезавтра он снова будет ехать этим же маршрутом, но номер его рейса должен быть 000002. Мне нужно распечатать этот номер в билете пассажира. Я подумал, что можно, но не знаю как, каждые 48 часов добавлять +1 к переменной, в которой хранится номер рейса.

Пока писал этот вопрос, у меня возник еще один.

Вопрос 2.

Я могу забронировать билет на месяц вперед, как тогда отобразить на билете актуальный номер рейса на дату бронирования?

Как можно это сделать? Подайте, пожалуйста, какую-то идею.

Сайт на wordpress.

Даже не знаю, какой код мог бы прикрепить к вопросу. Этот шаг пока реализуется только устно.

Comment: Не нужно делать никакие +1 к переменной. Каждый рейс - отдельная запись со своим номером. Ничего страшного не будет, если в билете через неделю будет номер 3, а билет на следующий день - 4.

Answer (score 0):

Если не отталкиваться от 48 часов: то просто ставите autoincrement на номер рейса в поле номер рейса, потом просто форматированием добиваете до нужно формата 00000N.
Если отталкиваться от 48 часов:
1 вариант: крон.
2 вариант: берете дату 1 рейса, записываете ее, и относительно нее отсчитываете сколько раз по 48 часов прошло.